# Getting same index when trying to get selected row index

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular and want to get index of rows inside the table when user clicks.When I try to get,it returns always 0.Because I have just one `tr` inside `tbody` but even I cange with `$('table td')` still getting same index.What should I change?

**Table in HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Student Number</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let studentsEl of items2">
          <tr>
            <td>{{studentsEl.name}}</td>
            <td>{{studentsEl.age}}</td>
            <td>{{studentsEl.stuNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{studentsEl.department}}</td>
            <td>
                    <img
                    [src]="studentsEl.imagePath"
                    alt="{{ studentsEl.name }}"
                    class="img-responsive"
                    style="max-height: 75px;"> 
            </td>       
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

**Typescript file of the component**

```
 constructor() {
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('table tr').click( function() {
          alert($(this).index());
      }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a couple of issues:

1. use `ngFor` for table row
2. You shouldn't use `dosument.ready` in constructor, but create a method and `click` handler.

Here is HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Student Number</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
          <tr *ngFor="let studentsEl of items2; let idx = index">
            <td>
               <span (click)="getIndex(idx)">
                   {{studentsEl.name}} yourIndex: {{ idx  }}
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>{{studentsEl.age}}</td>
            <td>{{studentsEl.stuNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{studentsEl.department}}</td>
            <td>
                    <img
                    [src]="studentsEl.imagePath"
                    alt="{{ studentsEl.name }}"
                    class="img-responsive"
                    style="max-height: 75px;"> 
            </td>       
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Your typescript file:

```
getIndex(idx){
    console.log(idx);
}
```

Comment: in this way,rows being duplicated and being in mess

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek Are you sure that rows are duplicated? We've just moved declaration of cycle, but not filling of your `items2`. Please, see where do you use `items` in your code.

Comment: thanks very much! TypeScript didn't work as you wrote so I kept mine.I just added my ngFor inside td block and added index variable.

Comment: I did it.I tried to vote for your answer but got system error.Sorry for being late